# Retrieve a column as a difference of 2 with laravel and Query Builder

Tags: sql, laravel, math, where-clause

I have 2 tables with a "Quantity" column on both.
I need to select columns part, name, color, (T1.quantity - T2.quantity) AS diff
from T1
with some joins on T2
where (T1.quantity - T2.quantity) > 0

With MySQL and phpMyAdmin i did this:

```
SELECT T1.part, T1.name, T1.color, (T1.quantity - T2.quantity) AS diff
FROM T1
JOIN T2
  ON  T1.part = T2.part 
  AND T1.color = T2.color
WHERE  T1.quantity - T2.quantity > 0
```

Can you help me doing the same with laravel and query builder?

I don't understand how to add an arithmetic calculation inside SELECT and WHERE clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
$query = DB::select(DB::raw("
             SELECT T1.part, T1.name, T1.color,
                (T1.quantity - T2.quantity) AS diff
             FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON 
                T1.part = T2.part AND T1.color = T2.color
             WHERE T1.quantity - T2.quantity > 0
"));
```

Comment: I tried with your solution but without success. I also scaled your query with this:

`$query = DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT T1.name, T1.part, T1.color, T1.quantity - 10 as Diff
        FROM T1'));`

and it didn't work. It seems the arithmetic calc give the problem because without the clause: `T1.quantity - 10` but with only `T1.quantity` works.

Comment: Ok now it works. The problem was on db tables. Quantities fields was UNSIGNED but i can have also negative results so after changed columns in DB it was all done.